Message: Declaration of Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\AbstractAdapter::offsetUnset() must be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset($offset)
I created a website some years ago using codeigniter 3. I uploaded it to cPanel and my hosting provider upgraded PHP to 8.1, then I started seeing this error on the website
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Compile Error

Message: Declaration of Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\AbstractAdapter::offsetUnset() must be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset($offset)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

The errors where more than this and I was able to resolve all of them except this particular one. The affected file is unknown and the error is related to phalcon.
The solutions I saw were all related to the phalcon php framework. I tried to add the CodeIgniter 3 keyword to my search on Google and couldn't find a suitable
The website was built using Codeigniter 3. The errors appeared after the hosting company made PHP 8.1 the default PHP version. At the moment, the errors appear on the homepage. I also noticed that the login and register functionality is no longer working

"then I started seeing this error on the website" - Please clarify this a bit more. Exactly when are you seeing this? On certain actions and/or pages? Is it everywhere? Where are you seeing these? In the logs? On the page? We also have no idea how your site is built, so we can't know if you might be using some library/composer package that uses/relies on something from the Phalcon framework. Or if you're looking at some log file containing logs for more applications than just yours.

Does this answer your question? How to solve this error: Declaration error in Phalcon

I can't seem to find any solution to this problem. I had to rebuild the entire project using Codeigniter 4
